# iOS 8.4 status bar animation glitch

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a `UITabBarController` which has embedded `UINavigationController`s. The status bar is showing on all of these embedded controllers. 
From this tab bar, I present a full-screen sign-in modal which has the status bar hidden. After dismissing the modal view controller, There are some very glitchy-looking animations (The navigation bar shifts down the height of the status bar as it animates in, leaving the content underneath the navigation bar. Then the content pops out from beneath the nav bar).

I'm using view-controller based status bar appearance. The glitches seem to occur only in iOS 8.4 (and is fine in 8.2).

Comment: Did you manage to fix the glitch? I've encountered the same issue. (resigning from view controller-based status bar appearance is not an option)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and to solve it I set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` in the `Info.plist` and used

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.None)
```

to hide and show the status bar